# Keep just dd-MM-yyyy in database date field

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form which have a field `Date`

My bean:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date dateDeclaration;
```

My Form:

```
<form:input path="dateDeclaration" type="text"/>
```

But when i put a date value like `03-12-1988`, in database it save like `03-12-1988 00:00:00`
How to eliminate the hours, minutes and seconds and keep just dd-MM-yyyy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your column most likely is a `DATETIME`. Use `DATE` instead.

Comment: thanks @NewInTheBusiness i change my column type in database from `DATETIME` to `DATE` and it's work.

Comment: i found the problem why in my jsp page it display `03-12-1988 00:00:00` when i stared my project in my entity bean i have this annotation `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` generated auto by hibernae tool so i delet it. and now i put it back and it's work but can somebody explain me why ?

Comment: [here](http://www.stateofmind.fr/confluence/display/SM/Utilisation+de+l'annotation+Temporal+en+JPA+2.0) but in frensh they expain very well the `@Temporal` annotation.

Comment: Hi. I'm facing the same problem, only my database field is already set to Date and I can't seem to be solving this problem.